# Twilio Chat JavaScript SDK getChannelByUniqueName now returns 403 forbidden

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Yesterday, I was able to create and switch between multiple private channels using the following code. Everything was working perfectly. I use a Twilio paid production account.

```
function setChannel() {
  // Retrieve private channel
  $scope.client.getChannelByUniqueName($scope.channelName).then(channel => {
    $scope.channel = channel;
    initMessages();
  }, error => {

    // Channel does not exists, create channel
    if (error.status == 404) {
      $scope.client.createChannel({
        isPrivate: true,
        uniqueName: $scope.channelName,
        friendlyName: $scope.channelName
      }).then(channel => {
        channel.join().then(channel => {
          $scope.channel = channel;
          initMessages();
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Today, when I try to access the channels the `getChannelByUniqueName` returns 403 Forbidden. I also note in the Twilio console that the channel admin I used to create and now use try to access the channels has its identity set to `Undefined`.

[image]

Today I create new channels and the channel admin identity is correctly set in the console. And everything works, but only with these new channels.

How can I now access the channels I have created yesterday?

**UPDATE:**
After several days, the newly created channels keep their identity. I consider this as solved for now.